# Mongoose - Retrieving object from ref query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got the following schemas:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    emailAddress: {type: String, set: toLower, index: {unique: true}},
});

var eventMemberSchema = new Schema ({   
    user: { type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User' },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var eventSchema = new Schema({
    id : String,
    name : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate : Date,
    venue : { type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Venue' },

    invitees : [eventMemberSchema],
});
```

What I'm trying to do, is query the events, with an invitation._id, and ultimately get back the user...

invitees->eventMember->user

So far i've got:

```
Event
.find({ "invitees._id": req.query.invitation_id })
.populate('user')
.run(function (err, myEvent) {

  console.log('error: ' + err);
  console.log('event:  '+ myEvent);
})
```

This works, and console shows the output of myEvent...
(I realise I don't need the populate part of my mongoose query above for this... i'm just testing)

I'm struggling on how to get, what I'd basically describe as: myEvent.invitees.user

**EDIT**

As an update...
This *works* - however, it kind of sucks, as now i'll need to do another db operation to get the user (i realise ref in mongoose does this under the hood)

```
Event
.findOne({ "invitees._id": "4f8eea01e2030fd11700006b"}, ['invitees.user'], function(err, evnt){
    console.log('err:  '+ err);
    console.log('user id:  '+ evnt.invitees[0].user); //this shows the correct user id
});
```

Comment: in 3.x replace .run() with .exec()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
Event
.find({ "invitees._id": req.query.invitation_id })
.populate('invitees.user')
```

**Update**:

Here is a working [gist](https://gist.github.com/2416177).