# Mongoose: How to query for a referenced object property?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get a list of documents from my database based on the property a sub-document. The models and schemas I'm using are:

```
var elementSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,

    _story: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' },

    date_created: Date,
    date_modified: Date,
};
var storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, default: '', trim: true},
    isPrivate: {type: Boolean, default: false},
});

mongoose.model("Story", storySchema);
mongoose.model("Element", elementSchema);
```

I'm trying to get all Elements that belong to a Story that is not private, and according to some posts I saw around here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214231/mongoose-retrieving-object-from-ref-query), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772982/finding-an-embedded-document-by-a-specific-property-in-mongoose-node-js-mongod), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587147/mongoosejs-using-find-to-find-by-reference)) the solution would be to use _story.isPrivate with find. I'm currently doing this:

```
Element.find({'_story.isPrivate': false})
         .populate('_story')
         .exec(function(err, elements){
             if(err){
                 return next(err);
             }
             else if(elements.length > 0){
                 return res.send(elements);
             }
             else{
                 return res.send(404, {message: "No elements found"});
             }
});
```

But the result is always an empty set (returns 404). With no condition, find returns all elements and populates _story correctly. I also activated the debug output to see the queries being executed and I get this:

```
Mongoose: elements.find({ '_story.isPrivate': false }) { fields: undefined, safe: undefined }
```

Trying to execute this in MongoDB I get no results. What can be wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support joins.  The `populate` of `_story` occurs after the `find` query completes so you can't reference its fields in the query.

Comment: But in the questions I linked they solved this same problem by using the query I used. I just can't get it to work with mine.

Comment: It only works if the story document is embedded in your element docs, not if it's a reference like in your case.

Comment: Question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201689/mongoose-find-a-document-by-reference-property

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Listen to @JohnnyHK. He speaks the truth. Mongodb queries use the data in one and only one and exactly one collection at a time. Since documents in the 'elements' collection  don't ever have a `_story.isPrivate` key path, `Element.find({'_story.isPrivate': false})` will never match any document. There are no joins in mongodb. Really. However, given the "no joins" constraint, it is still possible to build an application and meet use cases, but you need alternative schemas and query designs. Sometimes people denormalize their data and duplicate stuff. Sometimes you run multiple related queries, etc, etc.

Comment: And I'm guessing Mongoose doesn't provide any tool to cope with this, right?

Comment: Mongoose provides the `query.populate()` function, schema refs, embedded schemas, all of which address use cases that might be joins in a relational database in a way that works in harmony with a document database.

Comment: But given your current schema, no mongoose itself doesn't really have any relevant helpers AFAIK. However, most designs I've seen would end up changing their schema to get a use case working well. Of course it's all art and trade-offs as opposed to science, so the details of your application should guide your approach.

Comment: Thanks! Now I guess I'll have to rethink the database (again).

Comment: Try a web search for "mongodb schema recipes" to get some patterns and ideas.

Answer (score 4):

You could re-order your model and have

```
var storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, default: '', trim: true},
    isPrivate: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    elements: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Element'}]
});

Story.distinct('elements', {'isPrivate':false}, function(error, results) { 
  /* handle callback */ 
}
```

In this way you can issue a single call and get an aggragate of Elements.