# mongoose find a document by reference property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a first model Person:

```
var personSchema    = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    name: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

And a second model Couple:

```
var coupleSchema    = new Schema({
    person1: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }],
    person2: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Couple', coupleSchema);
```

I find a couple with a person ObjectId:

```
    Couple.find({
        'person1': req.params.objectid
    })
    .populate({
        path: 'person1 person2'
    })
    .exec(function (err, couple) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(couple)
    });
```

But I would like to find a couple by giving a firstname and not an ObjectId of a Person, something like that:

```
    Couple.find({
        'person1.firstname': "Bob"
    })
    .populate({
        path: 'person1 person2'
    })
    .exec(function (err, couple) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(couple)
    });
```

But it is always empty...

Anyway to solve this?

Thank you for any feedback.

## EDIT

I just implemented the answer:

Let's see my Couple model now:

```
var Person      = require('mongoose').model('Person');
var coupleSchema    = new Schema({
    person1 : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }],
    person2 : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

coupleSchema.statics.findByUsername = function (username, callback) {
  var query = this.findOne()

  Person.findOne({'firstname': username}, function (error, person) {
    query.where(
      {person1: person._id}
    ).exec(callback);
  })
  return query
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Couple', coupleSchema);
```

With this usage:

```
Couple.findByUsername(req.params.username, function (err, couple) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(couple);
    });
```

That works! Thank you for your answer and edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `couple` model, `person1` is an ObjectID (I know you know it), so it has no obviously no property `.firstname`.

Actually the best way to achieve this, is to find the user by it's first name, and then query the couple, with the `id` of the user.

This method could/should stand in the `couple` model as a static method (simplified code sample):

```
couple.statics.findByPersonFirstname = function (firstname, callback) {
  var query = this.findOne()
 
  Person.findOne({firstname: firstname}, function (error, person) {
    query.where($or: [
      {person1: person._id},
      {person1: person._id}
    ]).exec(callback);
  })

  return query
}
```

Just [like this exemple](https://gist.github.com/furf/5991442).

EDIT: Also note that the ref must be the `_id` (so you couldn't store with the first name, that would be a bad idea anyway).

### Considering your edit:

`Person._id` is maybe a `String` and the reference is an `ObjectId`, if so, try:

```
{person1: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Person._id)}
```

Also, your variable is `person` and not `Person`. Try to log `person` to see if you get something.

Finally, my code sample is really simple, don't forget to handle errors and all (see the link I gave you above, which is complete).

Comment: Ok I was just wondering if there is a way to deference the ObjectID to get the property. I will take your solution in that case. Thank you for helping!

Comment: You could also consider saving the first name of the persone in the couple. Or even saving the whole person, and removing the ref. In both cases you would have to update the couple when you update the person. This would be ok as long as a person can only be in one couple (as it would only be duplicated twice), and especially benefits if you also need to find couple by persons firstname, name, lastname, pseudo etc. And would save the `populate`.

Comment: I dont want to update the couple when a person is modified. That is why I use a ref in couple.

Comment: Yes sure, the first answer is probably the best option

Comment: A last point before validate the answer, how do you declare Person in Couple model? Because I have an issue at `coupleSchema.statics.findByPersonFirstname`: `Person.findOne is not a function`

Comment: Simply `import` or `require` your `Person` or model